# In Ruby, how do I define a class constructor method with the same name as the class?

Tags: ruby, constructor

I'm not sure where I have seen this, or if I just think I have seen it, but I would like to be able to call a method that creates an instance of a class with the same name. So, instead of:

```
# The class is called 'Vector3', for example:
Vector3.new(x,y,z)
```

I would like to have an eponymous method that instantiates the class, like so:

```
Vector3(x,y,z) #<- returns instance of Vector3 class
```

How would you define that in Ruby?

Comment: You could theoretically define a method `Vector3` which is an alias of `Vector3.new` in the `Kernel` module, but why?

Comment: How would you define a method named `foo` in Ruby? Then, how would you define a method named `Vector3` in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't. You can do something similar, `Vector3[x, y, z]`.

```
class Vector3
  def initialize(x, y, z)
    # ...
  end

  def self.[](*args)
    self.new(*args)
  end
end
```

Note that the Ruby library uses this device as well. There's `Hash.new(...)` and `Hash[...]` <strike>, but no `Hash(...)`.</strike> This parallels how `Proc` objects are invoked:

```
greet = Proc.new { |name| puts "Hello, #{name}" }
greet["Amadan"]
```

EDIT: I stand corrected:

```
module Kernel
  def Vector3(*args)
    Vector3.new(*args)
  end
end
```

But, as Eli Sadoff said, it is impractical, violates encapsulation, and Ruby style (functions and methods should be lowercase).

Comment: That's not really true. You can do `def Vector3(x, y, z); Vector3.new(x, y, z); end` in the `Kernel` module, but it's not practical.

Comment: Well, this is a nice solution, thanks! I will just use this (your initially proposed solution, that is).

Comment: @EliSadoff Is it possible to have a module method and class with the same name in the module to achieve this as an alternative?

Comment: It's been done for `Array`, `Float` and many others. Still, it's probably best not to pollute Kernel anymore. `"HelloWorld".send(:Vector3, x,y,z)` :-/

Comment: Your `self.[](*args)` proposal is a good one, but the accepted answer shouldn't have 2 wrong statements (`you can't` and `no Hash(...)`).

Answer (score 4):

As @Eli mentioned, you can define a method in the kernel:

```
def Kernel.Vector3(*args)
  Vector3.new(*args)
end
```

Ruby does this for `Array`, `Complex`, `Float`, `Hash`, `Integer`, `Rational` and `String` where you probably saw it.

The reason it works is that `Object` includes `Kernel`, hence all objects in your program (except ones directly inheriting from `BasicObject`) will have that method.

However, doing so is unidiomatic, unnecessary (you clutter all objects with an additional method), confusing (capitalized identifiers should be constants) and generally looked down upon.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going with Amadan's answer, as the general consensus seems to be that going the Kernel route is a bad idea. The array syntax is still nice and concise.

Answer (score 0):

This answers what I understood the question to be from the title. (Somehow I overlooked the example that contradicts that.) I will leave my answer because I think it includes some interesting elements.

```
class MyClass
  def hi
    "hi"
  end
  my_alias = to_s
  singleton_class.class_eval { alias_method(my_alias, :new) }
end

MyClass.methods(false) 
  #=> [:MyClass]
my_instance = MyClass.MyClass
  #=> #<MyClass:0x007fadc2092320>
my_instance.hi
  #=> "hi"
```

Note that this works when the alias of `new` is passed arguments and/or a block.

See [Object#singleton_class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) and [Module#class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval).

Comment: @DorianG, why did you delete you question? I was about to post an answer. Please consider undeleting it.